# Nuspec version from AssemblyInfo version

Tags: c#, powershell, tfs, nuget, nuget-package

i have a problem,in Team Foundation Service i would read a version from Assembly Info that is auto increased when i run a build.... and set this version in nupsec file to create a nuget package with the same number, ex

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.1")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.1")]
```

In tfs i can use power shell script but i don't know how to made this(i don't know power shell script). 
Can anyone help me or tell me a site when i find solution??
Thanks and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Provide TFS version please.

Comment: Sorry, it's Team Foundation Server 2017

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally i solved my problem, i found on tfs marketplace task that reads assembly version and sets automatically its value to nuspec file, so the nuget package version is the same of assembly.
To whom it may concern, the task name is:

Nuget version synchronizer
published by Cdiscount Alm

Thanks anyway for your help, guys

Comment: The GitHub repo for your project here isn't there anymore... Wanted to look at it first before using it... You still have the source for this task?

Comment: @user3773048 I don't understand which github repo you are referring to. My project was on TFS now AzureDevops

Comment: I was talking about the GitHub source for the TFS Marketplace task: "Nuget version synchronizer published by Cdiscount Alm".... Anyways, I've moved on from this problem, but would be nice maybe for others to see.

Comment: Unfortunately, as you were saying, it also seems to you that the user has removed the source code from Github, and we no longer use that task on our projects either, so I don't have the code

Comment: I thought you or your team published that task.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've already versioned your build.

You can use the same number for your NuGet package versionig.

Edit your build process.
Go to Options tab and set build number like $(date:yyyy.MM.dd)$(rev:.r)
Then go to Tasks tab, press Add Task, Package, NuGet Packager.

Expand "Pack Options" for this step and set Automatic package versioning to "Use the build number".

It's the easiest way to version your NuGet (but not the best).

I would recommend to create a variable like "YourProjectName_BuildNumber" for NuGet package versioning. More details about variables: [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/variables).

More details about PowerShell in TFS: [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/ru-ru/docs/build/steps/utility/powershell).